# Object not following path

Tags: animation, particles, path

I have set two particle systems to move along a path while emitting particles. However, I'm having two problems. Firstly, the particles are moving slower than the emitter object and therefore is creating a gap between them. Secondly, one of the particle system is not following the path accurately.

This is my set up:

[image]

As you will see, one of the particles systems is following the path consistently, while the other isn't.

PS : Crank up the particle count for both the particle systems to 10000 or higher to view an accurate representation.

**UPDATE:** PPS : How do I delay the start of the path animation for one of the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1: Fixing particles**

To fix this go to the particle system tab under *Velocity* and turn the *Object* option up to 1.00.

**Problem 2: Path follow**

To fix this, go to the start of the animation, select the path, go into *Edit* mode and, with all points selected, click *Toggle Cyclic* in the Tool Shelf. You should now see a gap in the path, which is the start and end. Determine which one is the start(the path lines are leading away from it) and select it. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and select *Cursor to Selected*. Click *Toggle Cyclic* and go back to object mode. Select the object to follow the path and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> again, this time choosing *Selected to Cursor*

**Problem 3: Delay animation start**

The only easy way to do this is to use a *Follow Path* constraint instead. It allows you to offset the animation. You could also just rotate the path with the object around the Z axis to start at a different place.

Also, I would but the animation end up to 100 for a smooth loop, if its going to be looping that is.

Comment: Toggle Cyclic? How do i do that?

Comment: Sorry, its in the Tool Shelf. Updated the answer.